# Como Solucionar el Error "C:xampp\xampp-control.ini" cual es su causa al igual que el Error EAccessViolation in module xampp-control.exe at 0025b2AE?

Tags: php, html, apache, xampp

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estimados compañeros como pueden apreciar me genera este error al salir de la aplicación de Xampp, específicamente al darle clic al botón de "quit" del Control Panel. Su gentil ayuda en la solución de dicho inconveniente y de el motivo por el cual se suscita.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Intenta en C://xampp/ dar click derecho en "xampp-control", le das en propiedades y ahí en compatibilidad, luego palomeas la opción "Ejecutar como administrador", guardas con aplicar y aceptar, luego le vuelves a dar click derecho y enviar a acceso directo en el escritorio, debería solucionar los problemas de acceso para xampp

Comment: Ese error es super comun, en mi clase todos tenemos el mismo error y nadie sabia como solucionarlo, gracias

Answer (score 1):

intenta cambiando los permisos a la carpeta, dándole control total a los usuarios.
quizás eso podría ayudarte a solucionar.
y en este momento me acaba de suceder a mi, realizando una instalación.

me da risa.. :)

este error es causado también, por no habilitar el AUC de la maquina.

solo debes ejecutar msconfig de la maquina y quitar todas las notificaciones.(recuerde, que esta operación afecta la seguridad del Host).